# Return value from imported module not working

Tags: python, import, module, return-value

I have a python file (project_root/usermodule/user_controls.py) with only the following code:

```
class UControl():
    def login(self):
        return 'John'
```

And I also have a class (project_root/main_file.py) that's importing user_controls (the file above) containing only the following code.

```
import os
from usermodule import user_controls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uc = user_controls.UControl()
    login_response = uc.login()
    if login_response == 'John':
        print login_response
```

When I run the second piece of code it gives no error but also no output (when I'm looking for it to output 'John').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found someone else who was having a similar problem. I just deleted the file, created a new one, pasted in my old code and compiled/ran it and it worked fine. Eclipse playing tricks on me. Thanks for viewing but this appears now to be solved.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a typo in the question or in your program: `login_reponse` != `login_response`

If I correct this error, the script runs flawlessly on my machine. (You may want to use `class UControl(object):` instead of `class UControl():`).

The fact that the error is not printed out, suggests that your code isn't even run. How are you invoking it?

Also, the second file, is actually a module (as the first one) and not a class as you are stating in your question.

Comment: Haha, the typo was only in the question. I cannot get this to work at all and can't see any reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: @JHarris: it also works for me.  Could you answer GaretJax's question about how you're invoking it?  The fact you're describing the module as a class makes me wonder if by "when I run" you mean "when I import", not "when I type 'python main_file.py'".  Double-underscore name will only be set to double-underscore main in the latter case.  [Wait, in the title you say 'from imported module', so this is probably it.]

Comment: @DSM: I think, when he speaks about 'imported module' he's referring to the 'user_controls' module (from which he expects a value from).

Comment: @DSM How GaretJax describes it is correct. Apologies for not being clear to start with.